# Android Phone book

Tags: android

Hi
 am using a custom phone book in my application, i want to make it dynamically updated when user edit/add new entries in android phone contact, currently i done it in onStart() ,but the problem is ,my application using some default intent,it cause the phone contact loader force to invoke,is there anyway to done this effectively.  I want to know that , when user edit/add new entries then only the phonecontact loader inoke,ie is there any lastmodification date or something in android phonebook, so that i can compare these date in onstart then invoke my phonecontact loader.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri, boolean, ContentObserver)`. You can reload data in a `Service` so your UI will work fast.

I've never tried it, so it's just an idea. Sorry if I'm wrong.